# Attaching 'active' class to faqfield expanded question

Tags: 7, navigation

I am using the [FAQ Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/faqfield) module my project which utilizes the jQuery Accordion UI and HTML definition lists, and I am wondering how I can attach an 'active' field to the expanded question. I would like to know so I can show/hide an up/down caret next to each of the questions based on it's active (expanded) state.  I am using Drupal 7.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is provided by FAQ Field using the jQuery Accordion UI.

In Structure > Content Types > Your Content type > manage display (admin/structure/types/manage/[your_content_type]/display), if you change your FAQ field display settings from Definition List to Accordion, an up/down caret is shown next to each question.

[image: FAQ Field display options]

If you click on the gear icon corresponding to your FAQ Field you can configure which question is active by default, as well as whether the questions are collapsible.

[image: FAQ Field accordion display settings]

Result:

[image: FAQ Field accordion]

The Accordion setting also adds the class `ui-state-active` to the active question element (an h3) and the class `ui-accordion-content-active` to the active answer element (a div).